# install gradel 5.4.1 using ansible-playbook

Tags: curl, ansible

I have installed gradel-5.4.1 manually using the command `sudo curl -O -k -L -v -X https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.zip`

Now I want to automate this task using an ansible-playbook. This is what i have tried, however it does not work. The playbook and the error message is below.

please help??

Playbook:

```
--- 
- hosts: servers
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: create a Directory /opt/gradle
      file:
        path: ~/opt/gradel
        state: directory
        mode: 0755

    - name: Unarchive a file that needs to be downloaded (added in 2.0)
      unarchive:
        src: https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip
        dest: ~/
        remote_src: yes
```

Error Message:

```
fatal: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failure downloading https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip, Request failed: <urlopen error unknown url type: https\\>"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you included a random backslash, but as the message clearly indicated, `https\` is not a legal protocol

```yaml
    - name: Unarchive a file that needs to be downloaded (added in 2.0)
      unarchive:
        src: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip
        dest: ~/
        remote_src: yes
```

I also have suspicions about `dest: ~/` because that `~/` nomenclature is a *shell* construct, and not an actual path, but it's possible ansible will use `os.path.expanduser` and you'll get away with it. Otherwise you'll want to replace that with `dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/"`

Comment: Thankyou, the code now works. Its weird because it still worked when i used the command to curl manually.

Comment: Also you was right about the destination. so i used dest: "<specified the path>". Thanks a load for the help again daniel

Comment: I'm glad it was something simple to fix. Please consider accepting the answer to let others know you don't need help with this anymore